# Server Error on Enabling IAP - Am I Missing Something?

Tags: google-iap

Whenever I try and enable IAP on a GKE Ingress via the console, I get the following error message:

> Invalid value for field 'resource.iap.oauth2ClientSecret': ''. IAP
>   OAuth2 client secret must be set if IAP is enabled.

Does anyone know what causes this?

It looks like an internal API error that's being returned via the GUI, and I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 3):

The GUI is indeed failing to perform an internal API call legally. You can enable IAP anyway by manually modifying your Ingress backend as follows:
`gcloud beta compute backend-services update $YOUR_INGRESS_BACKEND --project=$YOUR_PROJECT --global --iap=enabled,oauth2-client-id=$CLIENT_ID,oauth2-client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET`

Comment: see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/backend-services/update for details on the command

Answer (score 0):

There are five parts—OAuth credentials, Ingress, Service, Secret, BackendConfig. You'll need Kubernetes `1.10.5-gke.3` or later. [Enabling Cloud IAP for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto#kubernetes-configure) describes what you'll need to do to (or at least most of it).

OAuth—create Credentials for an OAuth client (probably "Web application" type). The ID and secret will go into a kube Secret object.

Ingress—points to your Service and nothing extra

Service—annotate with the BackendConfig. (You can assign different service ports to different backends. Use "default" for the simple case.)

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "mybc"}'
```

Secret—will hold the credentials for your created OAuth client

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: mysecret
data:
  client_id: xxx
  client_secret: xxx
```

BackendConfig—is a custom resource that GKE supports so there's nothing fancy to do beyond creating this object

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: mybc
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: mysecret
```

If you are still having trouble: review that documentation again; check the OAuth authorized domains; on the IAP page, confirm **IAP-secured Web App User** permissions for the intended users; check that your Secret data is base64 encoded; check the ports match across your Ingress/Service/Deployment specs.

Comment: Hi JCotton, thanks for your comment.

I'm aware of the process, the problem at the moment is that I can't follow it as the part of the GCP Console that I need to use is not working - it gives me the error shown in the question. I am confident that there isn't a problem in my configuration as I have successfully enabled IAP in a different environment with the same configuration - I just can't follow the process again as I'm getting this error from the console.

Comment: Ah, well it's good you've got all the pieces working together. Not good the GUI has bugs. Sounds like you have the workaround, which is via `gcloud` cli. I built my setup with `kubectl create` while watching the GUI console to test through it.